# Ruby: rand method is not giving me a truly random number

Tags: ruby, random

I am trying to answer the following question from Chris Pine "Learn to Program" book:

> • Write a Deaf Grandma program. Whatever you say to grandma (whatever
>   you type in), she should respond with HUH?!  SPEAK UP, SONNY!, unless
>   you shout it (type in all capitals). If you shout, she can hear you
>   (or at least she thinks so) and yells back, NO, NOT SINCE 1938! To
>   make your program really believable, have grandma shout a different
>   year each time; maybe any year at random between 1930 and 1950. (This
>   part is optional, and would be much easier if you read the section on
>   Ruby's random number generator at the end of the methods  chapter.)
>   You can't stop talking to grandma until you shout BYE. Hint: Don't
>   forget about chomp! 'BYE'with an Enter is not the same as 'BYE'
>   without one! Hint 2: Try to think about what parts of your program
>   should happen over and over again. All of those should be in your
>   while loop.
>
> • Extend your Deaf Grandma program: What if grandma doesn't want you
>   to leave? When you shout BYE, she could pretend not to hear you.
>   Change your previous program so that you have to shout BYE three times
>   in a row. Make sure to test your program: if you shout BYE three
>   times, but not in a row, you should still be talking to grandma.

My code is giving me the same "random_year" when I run it. Why is the code not providing me an actual random year (between 1930 and 1950)?

Code in ruby.

```
# Deaf Grandma

random_year = 1930 + rand(1950 - 1930)

puts 'WHAT DO YOU WANT KID?'

bye = 0
talk_to_grandma = nil

while bye < 3 
  talk_to_grandma = gets.chomp
  if talk_to_grandma == "BYE"
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + random_year.to_s
    bye+=1
    elsif talk_to_grandma == talk_to_grandma.upcase
      puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + random_year.to_s 
      bye = 0
    else  
      puts "HUH?! SPEAK UP, SONNY!"
      bye = 0
  end
end
```

Comment: BTW, you can use a range: `random_year = rand(1930..1950)`

Comment: The question ought to show how your program behaves: A transcript of you running it, and then you pointing out what's different between how it behaved and how it ought to behave would be good.

Answer (score 4):

You need to generate the random number inside your loop. Right now you generated it ONCE at the start of the program, and then it never changes. Basically:

```
while bye < 3 
    random_year = 1930 + rand(1950 - 1930)  // move the random generation to here
    puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + random_year.to_s
```

Comment: Just to be sure about the naming here: this is also not a "truly" random number as the title suggests, but a [pseudorandom rumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). Truly random numbers can only be generated by a truly random process, and a computer is one of the most "unrandom" things.

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned a value to the `random_year` variable in the first code line. It is selected randomly.

On each call to

```
puts 'NO, NOT SINCE ' + random_year.to_s
```

the variable is accessed/read, but not modified.

You may want to encapsulate the random year generation in a method:

```
def random_year( start=1930, range = 20 )
  start + rand( range )
end
```

then you can use it like this:

```
puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{random_year}"
```

or, for a slightly older grandma:

```
puts "NO, NOT SINCE #{random_year(1910, 50)}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For that exercise I've used:  `rand(1930..1950)`